# How to fix this excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this Excel sheet that I Need to perform a formula that gives me 1 if criteria are met and 0 if the criteria are not met.
This is the Excel sheet that i am working on :[image: Worksheet]

This is what I have tried for now. I tried with `vlookup`, `match` and `If` alone but I can't seem to get any results.

`=(IF(INDEX($H:$I;MATCH(1;($A2=$H:$H)*($B2=$I:$I);0);1&2);1;0))`

So basically, if column **A** & **B** have values that exists in column **H** & **I** then give 1 else give 0.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The problem is your textual column A and your custom formatted numeric column H. Those values wouldn't match on numeric `SEAG` values.

Comment: @JvdV with lit bit of adjustment it worked. Thank you

Comment: Try the following: `=IF(ISNUMBER(A2*1),SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$11=A2*1)*($I$2:$I$11=B2)),SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$11=A2)*($I$2:$I$11=B2)))`. Change the 11 reference to whichever is your last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same has been answered by @JvdV through comment and the same accepted by @Eidrizi

Here you go for that answer:

The problem is your textual column A and your custom formatted numeric column H. Those values wouldn't match on numeric `SEAG` values

and

**Try the following:**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2*1),SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$11=A2*1)*($I$2:$I$11=B2)),SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$H$11=A2)*($I$2:$I$11=B2)))
```

Change the 11 reference to whichever is your last row.

> Note: Answered behalf of @JvdV, because of the answer in comment and
>   question is in unanswered